# ошибка sql запроса (неизвестный столбец)

Tags: mysql

Подскажите почему не работает запрос по псевдонимному столбцу (time_work):

```
SELECT DATE_CREATE, 
NAME, 
PREVIEW_PICTURE, 
PREVIEW_TEXT, CODE,
b_iblock_element_property.VALUE AS time_work, 
b_iblock_element_property.VALUE AS V2, 
b_iblock_element_property.VALUE AS V3, 
b_iblock_element_property.VALUE AS V4, 
b_iblock_element_property.VALUE AS V5, 
b_iblock_element_property.VALUE AS V6, 
b_iblock_element_property.VALUE AS V7, 
b_iblock_element_property.VALUE AS V8, 
b_iblock_element_property.VALUE AS V9, 
b_iblock_element_property.VALUE AS V10, 
b_iblock_element_property.VALUE AS V11 

FROM `b_iblock_element`
RIGHT JOIN `b_iblock_element_property` 
ON b_iblock_element_property.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID = b_iblock_element.ID
WHERE IBLOCK_ID = 14 AND ACTIVE = 'Y' AND `time_work` LIKE '%:%'
ORDER BY `time_work` ASC
```

Сортировка работает (ORDER BY)
Идея в том что бы создать из одного столбца несколько разных столбцов с разной информацией, так вообще можно сделать?

Comment: Не понятна задача. Вам value нужно выбрать с разных строк?

Comment: есть VALUE, когда я запрашиваю его по конкретному ID приходит результат от 6 до 11 строк, вместо строк я хочу создать столбци. (Выбираю данные из битрикса) что бы была 1 строка и дополнительно 6-11 столбцов

Comment: потому что where выполняется до того, как появится столбец time_work. используйте вместо него b_iblock_element_property.VALUE и запрос будет работать

Comment: он то будет работать но тогда where сработает для всех остальных псевдонимных столбцов а мне надо что бы в каждом столбце был разный VALUE, или это никак сделать нельзя?

Comment: если нужно из одного столбца сделать несколько - смотрите в сторону pivot

Comment: или же формируйте столбцы подзапросами, если их к-во ограничено и Вы заранее знаете их.

Comment: Делал похожее на Postgres, встроенная функция называлась crosstab; вот что гуглится для mysql https://coderwall.com/p/thijma/creating-a-cross-tab-in-mysql. Может поможет.